# Beautiful Soup Img Src Scrape

Tags: python, python-3.x, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

**Problem:** I am trying to scrape the image source locations for pictures on a website, but I cannot get Beautiful Soup to scrape them successfully.

**Details:**

- [Here is the website](https://www.acefitness.org/resources/everyone/exercise-library/14/bird-dog/)
- The three images I want have the following HTML tags:

  - `<img src="https://ik.imagekit.io/02fmeo4exvw/exercise-library/large/14-1.jpg" style="display: none;">`
  - `<img src="https://ik.imagekit.io/02fmeo4exvw/exercise-library/large/14-2.jpg" style="display: none;">`
  - `<img src="https://ik.imagekit.io/02fmeo4exvw/exercise-library/large/14-3.jpg" style="display: none;">`

**Code I've Tried:**

- `soup.find_all('img')`
- `soup.select('#imageFlicker')`
- `soup.select('#imageFlicker > div')`
- `soup.select('#imageFlicker > div > img:nth-child(1)')`
- `soup.find_all('div', {'class':'exercise-post__step-image-wrap'})`
- `soup.find_all('div', attrs={'id': 'imageFlicker'})`
- `soup.select_all('#imageFlicker > div > img:nth-child(1)')`

The very first query of `soup.find_all('img')` gets every image on the page except the three images I want. I've tried looking at the children and sub children of each of the above, and none of that works either.

What am I missing here? I think there may be javascript that is changing the css `display` attribute from `block` to `none` and back so the three images look like a gif instead of three different images. Is that messing things up in a way I'm not understanding? Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The content is provided dynmaically via `JavaScript`, but not rendered by requests per se, unlike in the browser.

However, you can search for the `JavaScript` variable:

```
var data = {"images":["https://ik.imagekit.io/02fmeo4exvw/exercise-library/large/14-1.jpg","https://ik.imagekit.io/02fmeo4exvw/exercise-library/large/14-2.jpg","https://ik.imagekit.io/02fmeo4exvw/exercise-library/large/14-3.jpg"],"interval":600};
```

with regex [`re.search()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html#re.search) and convert its content string with [`json.loads()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/json.html#json.loads) to JSON, so that you can access it easily.

###### Example

```
import requests
import re, json

url = 'https://www.acefitness.org/resources/everyone/exercise-library/14/bird-dog/'

json.loads(re.search(r'var data = (.*?);', requests.get(url).text).group(1))['images']
```

Comment: This worked, thank you @hedgehog! Can you explain the magic json.loads line so I can understand?